# Find common values between all groups

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe

```
data.frame(reg=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3),jahr=c(1,2,3,4,3,4,1,2,3))
```

and I need to find the value of `jahr` that exists in each group `reg`, in the example it is 3. In real, there might also exist several matches (which should return a vector with all matches) or no matches (which should return NA). Guess it is easy with `dplyr`, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Reduce`, i.e.

```
Reduce(intersect, split(df$jahr, df$reg))
#[1] 3
```

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I needed. My question is indeed a duplicate. Sorry for that, did not find the entry before.